# Why Impulse has unit $\rm Ns$?

Tags: momentum, dimensional-analysis, si-units

We know Impulse is change in momentum and

also that units of momentum are $kg.m/s$

> Then how Impulse has units $\rm Ns$?

Comment: Do you know what a Newton is in terms of kilograms, meters, and seconds?

Comment: *We know Impulse is change in momentum.* [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_(physics)), like many physics textbooks, uses a different, but equivalent, definition of impulse: “the integral of a force, $F$, over the time interval, $t$, for which it acts.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impulse is a change of momentum during time interval $dt$. The change of momentum has dimensions of $kg \cdot m/s$. If we multiply $s$ both denominator and numerator, it gives $kg \cdot m \cdot / s^{2}$, where $kg \cdot m/s^{2}$ is a dimension of force, that is $N$. Thus, impulse has a dimension of $N\cdot s$

Answer (score 1):

In terms of dimensions [force] = [M][L][T$^{-2}$] and [time]=[T].

[impulse] = [force$\cdot$time] = [M][L][T$^{-2}$]$\cdot$[T]=[M][L][T$^{-1}$] $\Rightarrow$ Ns = kg m s$^{-1}$

Answer (score 1):

Dimension of impulse is $[LMT^-1]$   = m kg /s

f=ma    Dimension of force is $[MLT^-2]$   =  kg m / $s^2$

so unit of impulse can be N s or m kg/s